# Keep geting 403 error when run node-fetch in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

When I run this code on Heroku I keep getting error 403 but
when I run it from my local machine it works well:

```
const gift = "NlnmJThk3hbmpBppug"

const body = {
      "mobile": process.env.MOBILE,
      "voucher_hash": url
}

const fetch_res = await fetch(`https://gift.truemoney.com/campaign/vouchers/${gift}/redeem`, {
   method: "post",
   headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(body)
})
const data = await fetch_res.json()
const code = data.status.code

console.log(code)
```

Comment: You use `gift` in your request, but it doesn't seem to be defined.

Comment: I defined the gift but i don't show in this code so here is it (sorry for bad eng)

`const gift = "NlnmJThk3hbmpBppug"`